# MongoDB. Query elements of the array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

NodeJS
There is Array like this:   SelectedAnimals
With some elements, for example: "cat", "mouse", "bird"
How to create query to display all DB collection elements with **any** of these array elements for key: animal?

Example data:

```
1){animal: "dinosaur", color: "yellow", gender: "male"}
2){animal: "cat", color: "grey", gender: "male"}
3){animal: "giraffe", color: "yellow", gender: "female"}
4){animal: "mouse", color: "grey", gender: "male"}
```

Result would be:

```
{animal: "cat", color: "grey", gender: "male"}
{animal: "mouse", color: "grey", gender: "male"}
```

Because *cat* and *mouse* are elements of **SelectedAnimals** array
What query I ve tried:

```
var query = {animal:SelectedAnimals};
var query = {animal:{$all: {SelectedAnimals}}};
var query = {animal:{$elemMatch: {SelectedAnimals}}};
```

Comment: Have  you tried use `$in`? Instead of `$all`.

Comment: apparently, my mistake was that i didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use [$in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in)

your query should be like this

```
  var query = { animal: { $in: SelectedAnimals } }
```

you can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D1Xg8qrPr9Z)

hope it helps